# Where should my Python package add files on a user system?

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, anaconda, pypi

I want my package to add a SQLite file either at time of package install or upon running an initialization method.

Is there a conventional place where that file should live?

- *Option 1:* within a [`/usr/local`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html#:%7E:text=Purpose,but%20not%20found%20in%20%2Fusr%20.) directory.
- *Option 2:* within `~` home directory of `/Users/<current_user>`

I have no experience in this area, but I am leaning toward a hidden `.my_package` directory at `~` because when I look at my home this is what I see:

```sh
.conda
.docker
.ipython
.jupyter
.matplotlib
...
```

Comment: @Abhilash That's for temporary files, not preferences etc. that are meant to be stored.

Comment: Various packages that I use leave their data in `~/.package_name` or `~/.package_name_data` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use the [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) package to determine the correct directory regardless of platform.

Comment: Hmm. So when I nav to that dir, I see mostly platform specific fullblown gui apps. E.g. chrome, slack, spotify, sublime.

Comment: Nevertheless, `appdirs` follows platform guidelines – those are the places where you're supposed to store data. E.g. on Windows where `AppData/Roaming` can actually live on a server (domain-joined accounts) it does make a difference.